# Azure DevOps NuGet task just started failing (missing dotnet core)

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

I have recently discovered that my Azure DevOps pipeline has started failing. Originally I assumed I had broken it with my recent changes however if I run the same commit on the same branch (**NOTE that I have renamed master to main**) then it fails when it had previously succeeded:

[image]

Here is my YAML for the pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: "NuGet Restore"
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'

- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: "NET 4.0 Build"
  inputs:
    solution: '**\Expressive.csproj'
    configuration: 'Release'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    testRunTitle: 'Run all tests'
```

I have discovered this detail in the build log:

```
Errors in D:\a\1\s\Source\CSharp\Expressive\Expressive.Tests\Expressive.Tests.csproj
    Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 3.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'.
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.dotnethostresolver/2.0.0/microsoft.netcore.dotnethostresolver.2.0.0.nupkg 39ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.dotnethostresolver/2.2.0/microsoft.netcore.dotnethostresolver.2.2.0.nupkg 37ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.dotnethostresolver/2.1.0/microsoft.netcore.dotnethostresolver.2.1.0.nupkg 38ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.serialization.json/4.0.2/system.runtime.serialization.json.4.0.2.nupkg 953ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.xml.xpath.xmldocument/4.0.1/system.xml.xpath.xmldocument.4.0.1.nupkg 955ms
```

So to summarise the only difference I can see is the fact that I have renamed `master` to `main`. I would be rather surprised if this is the cause of the problem though. Has anyone seen this or are able to provide assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

As workaround , switch to dotnet restore task to solve this issue .

Troubleshooting:

You can try to check the nuget version used by the nuget restore task in the pipeline running on the master branch. Then compare it with the nuget version used in pipeline running on the main branch to see if they are consistent.

[image]

If they are inconsistent, you can add a NuGet tool installer task to the main branch pipeline to use the same nuget version as the master branch pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I can confirm that both master and main are detecting the same version of NuGet `Detected NuGet version 4.1.0.2450 / 4.1.0`. One detail I have noticed though is that the NuGet Restore task versions are different. Master (working) is `2.169.2` and Main (failing) is `2.171.1`. I will see if I can force the older version on this branch and see if that makes a difference

Comment: I'll be honest I haven't been able to work out if I can specify a specific version of a Task to use

Comment: `renamed master to main` I am confused about this, there should be no such feature  in azure devops, how did you do it? In addition, you can check whether the source of the two build runs are different.

Comment: Sorry I hadn’t renamed master to main inside Azure DevOps. I am sourcing the code from GitHub and had renamed that branch there. I only mentioned it as it was the only environmental difference I could see. You can see from my screenshot that the pipeline is building the commit each time. I have worked around the issue now and can update this post once I am back on my laptop.

Comment: So I switched from using the NuGet restore over to using a `dotnet restore` as you can see here https://github.com/bijington/expressive/blob/main/azure-pipelines.yml

Comment: Glad to hear that this issue can be solved by using `dotnet restore` task instead. I added this workaround to the answer.